# How should we tag questions on @solana/web3.js?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Seeing a number of questions using the tag `solana-web3.js`, `web3`, `web3js`, and `web3.js`. These are all synonyms of the same tag.

Which tag should be used for these questions?